# Simple display html element with ng-include

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to Angular and JavaScript. I want to use ng-include to import elements form htmls, the elements are simple for display. To illustrate, here I have 3 html files, "123.html", "456.html", and "789.html".

For "123.html":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<p> Here we have 123. </p>
<div class="container">
  <div ng-include="'456.html'"></div>
  <div ng-include="'789.html'"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

For "456.html":

```
<div>
    <P> Here is the 456. </P>
</div>
```

And for "789.html":

```
<div>
    <P> And here is the 789. </P>
</div>
```

I see some ng-include examples, but all of them got ng-controller and additional JavaScript file. So my question is, if I just want to display html elements, do I still need ng-controller for the code?

P.S. The code above cannot correctly work, could someone help figure out the problem for this very simple example? The browser is Firefox. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Angular must at least have the module `myApp` available since that's what you are declaring in `ng-app`

It can't bootstrap without that module and errrors in your browser console should be telling you that it can't find it.

If all you are doing is using angular for includes why not just use server side includes?

Comment: Could you be more specific how to use server side includes? Or is there any link or example? Thanks.

Comment: Additionally, is np-app required or optional? Can I just ng-include without np-app?

Comment: Any server side programming language can include files within files

Comment: You have to bootstrap angular somehow if you use angular. You can (I forgot) use `ng-app` without a value as noted in other answer

Answer (score 1):

So you don't have an app called `myApp` and would get an error referencing a module that is not defined.  In the code below you can see I removed it.

That being said you can define templates using the `script` tag with `ngTemplate`.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="456.html">
  <div>
    <P> Here is the 456. </P>
  </div>
</script>
```

[Example using both a `script` template and a separate file.](http://plnkr.co/edit/JApTGTo7uSfBLAnNKQZm?p=preview)

#### This is the full working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app>
<p> Here we have 123. </p>
<div class="container">
  <div ng-include="'456.html'"></div>
  <div ng-include="'789.html'"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="456.html">
  <div>
    <P> Here is the 456. </P>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="789.html">
  <div>
    <P> And here is the 789. </P>
  </div>
</script>
</body>

</html>
```